# Dialogue from the motion picture " Captain America - The First Avenger".What is she implying in this sentence?

Tags: dialogue

This is a dialogue from the motion picture " Captain America - The First Avenger":

> **Steve Rogers**: Well, what about you and Stark? How do I know you two
>   haven't been...fonduing?
>
> [*she turns to look at him*]
>
> **Peggy Carter**: You still don't know a bloody thing about women!

What does Peggy Carter want Steve Rogers(Captain America) to know about women,when she says - "*You still don't know a bloody thing about women*"?

Comment: He [mistook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNLmOmp1PNI) it for [fondle](http://media.tumblr.com/ff8b2a3b304596894a367683f3e395d9/tumblr_inline_mmagrzXlqx1qz4rgp.gif)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about English Language but about interpersonal relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't recall the scene from the film, but fondue and thereby fonduing didn't exist as a thing during WWII, hence Steve Rogers uses the phrase clumsily.

The implication is that Steve Rogers is implying that surely Peggy Carter has been dating Howard Stark, or at least he suspects that could be the case - and why wouldn't he, as Howard Stark is, after all, a millionaire playboy.

Her reply is that she clearly thinks Stark isn't her type; too showy, too brash, too much of a playboy - the fact that Rogers can't see this just shows how he doesn't know anything about women, how they think and feel and how innocent his understanding of romance and the opposite sex really is.

She want's him to understand that there's more to falling for someone than their showboating, flash cars, and wallet!

Answer (score -1):

"You still don't know a bloody thing about women"?

*A bloody thing* means *nothing*, in a vulgar sense.

Comment: Not quite.  "Bloody" is a figurative, intensifying oath.  It means "nothing" here (or more accurately "not a damned thing") because of "don't know."  It is an interesting word with an interesting history.  Why not look it up and resubmit your answer?  For my tastes under a different nym, but it's up to you of course.